# Mac OS Lion Terminal: Add blank line after command output?

Tags: macos, terminal.app, .bash-profile

How can I configure my `.bash_profile` to add a blank line after any command output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to adjust the shell prompt; the default shell is bash, and it will happily inject a newline into the prompt by embedding `\n` in the appropriate variables.  (PS1 by default.)

More details at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tip-prompt/ or in the manual page - though that is a much more pleasant reference.

Comment: My shell is bash and below is what I currently have: 
export PS1="\u:\w
- "

With above if I add "\n" at the end then the new line gets added immediately after the second line hyphen "-" and not after command output. I am looking for something that would add new line after command execution.

Comment: Try putting the newline at the *start* of your prompt. :)

Answer (score 7):

Add the following line at the end of `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`, whichever exists:

```
PS1="\n$PS1"
```

This will add a newline *before* a prompt is printed, which is after control is returned to the shell.

Unless your command prompt contains shell commands or variables (which would get executed/interpreted at the time of variable assignment), this will work. Otherwise, just prepend the `\n` to your original prompt definition.

Comment: In more recent version of OS X this file was renamed to: `~/.profile`

Comment: @MarcusBöhm: Completely different file, see e.g. `man bash`, section `INVOCATION`. However, if you've never changes anything, the files I mention may not exist.